# Integration test fails in my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I'm working on integration tests in my Spring Boot application. And I use H2 database for testing.

I get

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

after I run assertTrue(userServiceImpl.checkIfUserIsNull(1L)); in isUserNullCheck in UserServiceTest. I think I set up the database properly but the test always fails and I can't find the problem.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email,
            Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", userName='" + userName + '\'' + ", password='" + "*********" + '\''
                + ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' + ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' + ", email='" + email + '\''
                + ", roles=" + roles + '}';
    }
}
```

Userservice

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

    public Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);

    public void save(CrmUser crmUser);

    void deleteById(Long theId);

    public boolean checkIfUserIsNull(long id);

}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName) {
        // check the database if the user already exists
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(CrmUser crmUser) {
        User user = new User();
        // assign user details to the user object
        user.setUserName(crmUser.getUserName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(crmUser.getPassword()));
        user.setFirstName(crmUser.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(crmUser.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(crmUser.getEmail());

        // give user default role of "CUSTOMER"
        Optional<Role> roleCustomer = roleRepository.findRoleByName("ROLE_CUSTOMER");
        log.info("The role " + roleCustomer);
        if (!roleCustomer.isPresent()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The role is not found");
        } else {
            user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(roleCustomer.get()));
        }
        // save user in the database
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(Long theId) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("delete from User where id=:userId");
        theQuery.setParameter("userId", theId);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        log.info("user is present: " + user.isPresent());
        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        log.info("password: " + user.get().getPassword());
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.get().getUserName(), user.get().getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.get().getRoles()));
    }
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        if (roles == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean checkIfUserIsNull(long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
        return user.isPresent();
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "user"\\;SET SCHEMA "user";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

sql.script.create.user1=INSERT INTO "user" (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,email) VALUES \
  (1,'john','$2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K','John','Doe','john@luv2code.com')
sql.script.create.user2=INSERT INTO "user" (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,email) VALUES \
  (2,'mary','$2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K','Mary','Public','mary@luv2code.com')
sql.script.create.user3=INSERT INTO "user" (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,email) VALUES \
  (3,'susan','$2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K','Susan','Adams','susan@luv2code.com')


sql.script.create.role1=INSERT INTO `role` (id,name) VALUES (1,'ROLE_CUSTOMER')
sql.script.create.role2=INSERT INTO `role` (id,name) VALUES (2,'ROLE_ADMIN')

sql.script.create.users_roles.user1=INSERT INTO `users_roles` (user_id,role_id) VALUES (1, 1)
sql.script.create.users_roles.user2=INSERT INTO `users_roles` (user_id,role_id) VALUES (2, 2)
sql.script.create.users_roles.user3=INSERT INTO `users_roles` (user_id,role_id) VALUES (3, 2)

sql.script.delete.user=DELETE FROM user
sql.script.delete.role=DELETE FROM role
sql.script.delete.users_roles=DELETE FROM users_roles
```

UserServiceTest

```
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private static JdbcTemplate jdbc;
@Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceTest.class);

    @Value("${sql.script.create.user1}")
    private String sqlCreateUser1;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.user2}")
    private String sqlCreateUser2;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.user3}")
    private String sqlCreateUser3;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.role1}")
    private String sqlCreateRole1;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.role2}")
    private String sqlCreateRole2;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.users_roles.user1}")
    private String sqlCreateUsersRolesUser1;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.users_roles.user3}")
    private String sqlCreateUsersRolesUser2;

    @Value("${sql.script.create.users_roles.user3}")
    private String sqlCreateUsersRolesUser3;

    @Value("${sql.script.delete.user}")
    private String sqlDeleteUser;

    @Value("${sql.script.delete.role}")
    private String sqlDeleteRole;

    @Value("${sql.script.delete.users_roles}")
    private String sqlDeleteUsersRoles;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupDatabase() {
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUser1);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUser2);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUser3);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateRole1);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateRole2);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUsersRolesUser1);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUsersRolesUser2);
        jdbc.execute(sqlCreateUsersRolesUser3);
    }

    @Test
    public void isUserNullCheck() {
        assertTrue(userServiceImpl.checkIfUserIsNull(1L));
        assertFalse(userServiceImpl.checkIfUserIsNull(0L));
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterAll() {
        jdbc.execute(sqlDeleteUser);
        jdbc.execute(sqlDeleteRole);
        jdbc.execute(sqlDeleteUsersRoles);
    }
}
```

I checked the sql statements and the code. They seem fine. I can't find the problem.

Comment: For starters stop mixing JUnit4/JUnit5. `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is for JUnit4, your `@BeforeEach` indicates JUnit5.

Comment: I got "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.myshoppingdemo.service.UserServiceImpl.checkIfUserIsNull(long)" because "this.userServiceImpl" is null
" after I commented out @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: @Connor for junit5, use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

One of the first issues I have noticed is basically using Junit4 and Junit5 interchangeably which is wrong and can cause weird issues. Another piece of advice is basically while running Integration Tests make sure that either you are running your tests on completely new H2 instances, or in the `beforeEach` delete all records and let each test setup the needed data. Otherwise you will start coupling your test data which could lead to fuzzy results depending on your tests run